# how we fill some values of array to another array that contain the null values by index

Tags: php, arrays

**Bellow is my Array that contain the null value**s

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [1] => 
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

**and bellow is my other array that contain some values of main index 3,5,6** now i wish the values of the bellow array (3,3,3) i want to put the above array that contain the null values please guide me how i put the bellow array values to above array null spaces according to main index

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [4] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

so after filling i want result like bellow
so for clearance i use single quotes that's show the filling values

Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 9
        )

```
[3] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 6
        [3] => '3'
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [1] => 4
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 7
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 4
        [3] => ' 3'
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [1] => '3'
        [2] => 6
        [3] => 8
    )
```

)

Comment: i want to merge some values according to main index.....fill null values with values so i confuse how i do that

Comment: define the result your want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this

```
$nulls = [
    2 => [1 => 2, 2=> 4, 3 => 9],
    3 => [1 => 4, 2=> 6, 3 => null],
    4 => [1 => 4, 2=> 6, 3 => 7],
    5 => [1 => 2, 2=> 4, 3 => null],
    6 => [1 => null, 2=> 6, 3 => 8] ];

$fills= [3 => [2 => 3],5 => [4 => 3],6 => [2 => 3]];


foreach ( $fills as $key => $val ) {
    $nulls[$key][array_search('',$nulls[$key])] = array_values($val)[0]; 
}

var_dump($nulls);
```

this will search the null values over the first array.

`$nulls` array is the array where you have the null values,
`$fills` array is the array where you have the values with the keys you want to fill

this loops the `$fills` array and search every key on the `$nulls` array and looks for the nulls

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array1 = [
    2 => [1 => 2, 2=> 4, 3 => 9],
    3 => [1 => 4, 2=> 6, 3 => null],
    4 => [1 => 4, 2=> 6, 3 => 7],
    5 => [1 => 2, 2=> 4, 3 => null],
    6 => [1 => null, 2=> 6, 3 => 8]
];

$array2 = [
    3 => [2 => 3],
    5 => [4 => 3],
    6 => [2 => 3]
];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if(true === array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
        foreach($value as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
            if(null === $innerValue) {
                $array1[$key][$innerKey] = '\''.current($array2[$key]).'\'';
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($array1);
```